# Return array from symfony 2 controller action

Tags: php, symfony

```
I need to return $items array from 'http://localhost:8000/cart/viewall'
controller action. But all i get is this error.
```

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "array" given.

This is my code,

```
 /**
 * @Route("/cart/viewall")
 * @Template()
 */
public function viewallAction() {
    $items = array(1 => 'item 1', 2 => 'item 2');        
    return new Response($items);
}
```

It would be great help if someone can supply a solution.

Comment: `new JsonResponse($items);` and you have to use the good `use ....\JsonResponse;`

Comment: What do you mean with "I need to return an array"? The controller in Symfony is responsible to return a response and since an HTTP response contains a body which is just a string your response must contain a string to. Do you maybe mean you want to return a JSON encoded array?

Comment: Think about the `new Response` like a call to `echo`. This is a response to the browser and it has to be a string.

Comment: Thanks I think I have to return a json array then.

Comment: How do you use the result from /cart/viewall? Ajax or what?

Comment: need to use in another action but I'll json decode it

Comment: And? Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `JsonResponse` instead.

Example :

```
$items = array(1 => 'item 1', 2 => 'item 2');
return new JsonResponse($items);
```

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html